# C++ method to call a specific function without if/elseif/elseif/elseif/else

Tags: c++, class

I want to create a function that takes a string that might be :
**"triangle" , "square", or "rectangle"**

And according to this argument, I want to return a pointer on a class Form.

I have a mother **class "Form"**, who inherits of **"Class Rectangle", "Class Square", and "Class Rectangle"**
But I don't want to do :

```
if (name == "rectangle")
    return (new Rectangle());
else if (name == "square")
    return (new Square());
... etc
```

I thought about pointers on functions, but I wanted the simplest method and clean code, what do you recommand ?

Thank's !

Comment: why do you not want to use the code that works and does the job?

Comment: i want a clean way to do it, imagine if I had 500 forms :)

Comment: why do you think this is not clean? This is the cleanest I can think of. No matter how many, say you have 1000 classes then still you will need to map the string to the constructor call somehow. And your code does that

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 first of all cascade `if` can be quite inefficient for 1000 string lookups

Comment: @Slava thats about efficiency not cleaness, though point taken. I'll shut up :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could use function pointers or lambdas.  You can use a `map` of strings to functors:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<ShapeBase*()>> actions = {
    { "rectangle", []{return new Rectangle;} },
    { "square", []{return new Square;} }
};

return actions[name]();
```

But if you're not going to change the actions at run time, it's hard to beat what you had really.

In a comment you asked "Imagine it had 500 forms".  Indeed, the map lookup will be faster than 500 chained `if` statements.  You could make it a `switch` with some effort:  use hashes for the names instead of the strings themselves.  If the hash function is `constexpr` you can write that easily:

```
switch (hash(name)) {
    case hash("rectangle"): return new Rectangle;
    case hash("square"): return new Square;
    // 500 cases
   }
```

The `switch` statement will be optimized to do a binary search or something like that, on the integer hash values.  You'll also get a compile-time error if there is a hash clash.

Comment: You better use `std::unordered_map` for hash, you assume that hash is always unique but that is not true so your code can have false positive.

Comment: there is no map for the hash.  It is a `switch` statement, and the cases must be unique at compile time.

Comment: yes but generated hash does not have to be unique and it is possible that unregistered string will create unrelated class which is quite a nasty bag which will be not easy to catch

Comment: I'd make the container `static const` if you're going this route.  You probably also want to check that the key is in the container.

Comment: If you use a good hash function (like murmurhash) you should not expect a collision for any reasonable string.

Comment: @Slava If you have a strong hash function it'll be pretty hard to come up with a colliding word - and even if one does figure out that "jhsdflkjshdfglshjgdufihluisdfhgisfhdklhl" leads to the same hash as "rectangle" - so what? If the user wants to use that - let him/her :-)

Comment: @Slava As long as the hash is reproducible, you won't get the wrong type. If a two cases have the same hash, the compiler should complain about non-unique `case` labels. I prefer using a map, but I don't think there is anything definitely wrong with using `switch`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do not like to write code which correctness  relates on pure luck, especially that can be made certain using one string comparison. And you do not need to write code for that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux problem is by mistake for example word "rectuangle" can be used at runtime and by bad luck that would generate same hash as "circle" - good luck find that problem. Or maybe `std::unordered_map` creaters did a stupid job checking for hash collision?

Comment: @Slava That's a good mindset. "pure luck" is a bit of an exaggeration though. :-) I guess the hash-switch could be expanded with a check for equality in each `case` to do what hash based containers do too. `case hash("square"): if(name == "square") ...` Perhaps packaged in a macro.

Comment: @TedLyngmo right or simply use `std::unordered_map` and not reinvent a bicycle

Comment: @Slava I agree. I'd use that. I assume OP used the switch to show an alternative that can be very effective for compile time constant maps.

Comment: @TedLyngmo whether or not you need to double-check the actual name when the hash matches depends on the quality and size of the hash.  If it's a cryptographic hash, you don't.  Don't use a macro.

Comment: @JDługosz For a hash to be truly safe against collisions it'd need to have at least the same length as the original message. Crypto hashes have strong collision resistance, but they are not immune. You can't use a function relying on a secret (HMAC etc) on top of the cryptographic hash function, because anyone could disassemble the program and find the secret.  Also, the hash sum must be `constexpr` which limits the word length considerably. So, yes, the check for equality is necessary to be 100% sure.

Comment: @TedLyngmo using 64-bit murmurhash, can you even _find_ a different string that produces the same hash as the strings of interest?

Comment: @JDługosz Theoretically, yes. In the words of Daniel Lemire: "_When MurmurHash is used as a deterministic function (without randomization), then the answer is that you can find two keys that always collide. With 100% probability. How do I know this? Simply because there are more strings that you can hash than there are hash values. So you must have collisions._". I'm not saying that it's practical, but collisions do exist, so you need to check to be 100% sure.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the Pigeonhole Principle applies to _any_ hash.  But in `git` we don't worry about a collision existing (except for hard-coding to identify the known exploit, which took years of computer time to even find).  To find a collision for "rectangle" you would need to try up to 1.85e19 strings.  I don't mean theoretically: I mean literally in fact can you find one?

Comment: @JDługosz Slava was out for 100% certainty - as in, "no other string can ever trigger the case now or in the future". Since a collision _can_ happen (by accident or by some future cracker), you _must_ test for equallity to be 100% certain.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why doesn't that reasoning apply to `git`?  The entire file is represented by a 120-bit hash and it doesn't double-check that the content matches.  For some objects, there's really no way to do such a check since the "whole thing" is not saved.  If you have sufficient bits in the hash, you don't worry about it.  After all, it's _possible_ that all the air in the room will rush into one corner, but you don't take precautions against it -- you assume it "never happens" even though it's _possible_.

Comment: I don't disagree. Note that my first comment on the subject was "so what?". The only reason to add the equallity check is to eradicate any doubt and go from extremely confident to 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::unordered_map`:

```
using FormPtr = std::unique_ptr<Form>;
using Creators = std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<FormPtr()>>;

FormPtr create( const std::string &name )
{
    const static Creators creators {
        { "triangle", [] { return std::make_unique<Triangle>(); } },
        { "square", [] { return std::make_unique<Square>(); } },
        { "rectangle", [] { return std::make_unique<Rectangle>(); } }
    };
    auto f = creators.find( name );
    if( f == creators.end() ) {
        // error handling here
    }
    return f->second();
}
```

If you need to add creators outside you can put them into a class and allow them to update the map and register more creators dynamically.